# Excel - Count unique values that match ID, optimized for 100,000+ cases

Tags: excel, count, excel-formula, match, unique

in reference to the excel screen capture below, I'm looking for a formula solution that counts the number of unique values in Column B (Colour) for each ID number in Column A.

I've imputed the desired result in Column C. So, for instance, ID 1 (A2) has only one unique colour, Grey (B2), which would return a 1 in C2. ID 2 has only one unique colour, yellow (B3, B4), and returns 1 in C3 and C4. ID 3, has two unique colours, Blue and Purple, thus returning a 2 in C5 through C8. Etc.

Because this will be run for close to 100,000 rows, many of the index and/or match based solutions I've come across take way to long to compute. I have found that the ID values, which are all in ascending order, can be used to speed things up by starting the formula with =IF(A2=A1, or something like this. Thanks in advance to anyone with some ideas about how to solve this with a lean formula.

Note: I am working with files that also have close to 100 columns. A solution that doesn't require helper columns would be ideal.

EDIT/ADDITION: In my main data file, there are instances of blank cells in column B. Is there a way to ignore the blank cells when counting for column C results?

[image]

Comment: To do this fast, without helper columns, a VBA solution would be best.

Comment: Thanks Ron, I'm definitely open to VBA if it's the most efficient route.

Comment: Try my answer below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a VBA routine that should run quickly for that number of entries.  We create a Class Module (User Defined Object) that consists of a collection (Dictionary) of Colors associated with each ID, and an count of that color. (Don't really need the count but it is trivial to add it in, in case you want it for some other purpose; and also as a demonstration of some of what could be done).

Then we output the results in the adjacent column, as you show in your screen shot.  The results could be output elsewhere, even on a different worksheet, with minor code changes.

Be sure to read the notes at the beginning of the modules for important information and about setting things up properly.

### Class Module

---

```
Option Explicit
'RENAME this module:  cID

Private pID As String
Private pColor As String
Private pColors As Dictionary

Public Property Get ID() As String
    ID = pID
End Property
Public Property Let ID(Value As String)
    pID = Value
End Property

Public Property Get Color() As String
    Color = pColor
End Property
Public Property Let Color(Value As String)
    pColor = Value
End Property

Public Property Get Colors() As Dictionary
    Set Colors = pColors
End Property
Public Function ADDColor(Value As String)
    'Might as well also count # of times this color assigned
    If Not pColors.Exists(Value) Then
        pColors.Add Key:=Value, Item:=1
    Else
        pColors(Value) = pColors(Value) + 1
    End If
End Function

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set pColors = New Dictionary
End Sub
```

---

### Regular Module

**EDIT** (*edited to eliminate count for blank rows*)

---

```
Option Explicit
'Set reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime (Tools/References)

Sub IDColorCount()
    Dim cID As cID, dID As Dictionary
    Dim wsData As Worksheet, rData As Range
    Dim vData As Variant, vRes As Variant
    Dim I As Long

'Set the data worksheet and range
'Read the data into an array for faster calculations
Set wsData = Worksheets("sheet1")
With wsData
    Set rData = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)).Resize(columnsize:=2)
    vData = rData
End With

'Go through the data and collect the information
Set dID = New Dictionary
For I = 2 To UBound(vData, 1)
  If Not vData(I, 1) = "" Then
    Set cID = New cID
    With cID
        .ID = vData(I, 1)
        .Color = vData(I, 2)
        .ADDColor .Color

        If Not dID.Exists(.ID) Then
            dID.Add Key:=.ID, Item:=cID
        Else
            dID(.ID).ADDColor .Color
        End If
    End With
  End If
Next I

'Size the results array
ReDim vRes(1 To UBound(vData), 1 To 1)
vRes(1, 1) = "Count"
For I = 2 To UBound(vData, 1)
    If Not vData(I, 1) = "" Then _
        vRes(I, 1) = dID(CStr(vData(I, 1))).Colors.Count
Next I

'The results can  be written anyplace
With rData.Offset(0, 2).Resize(columnsize:=1)
    .EntireColumn.Clear
    .Value = vRes
End With

End Sub
```

---

Comment: Oh wow! This runs perfectly on a 70,000 row test, takes ~ 5-10 seconds using (i7-2600K CPU @ 3.40GHz; 16GB RAM; 64 bit WIN 10; Excel 2016). Unbelievable, I can't believe how fast this is, thank you!  I had forgotten that there are the occasional blank cells in the large list. Is there a way to adjust the VBA to run as it does but exclude the blank cells from the count. Currently they are counted as unique values.

Comment: Test the array just before the `Set cID` line. Eg: `If Not vData(I,1) = "" Then ...`. Curious, what is the speed of the formula solution?

Comment: @sociologix OK, I edited the code to remove counts for blank lines (where column A is blank; I did not test Column B, but you could add that).  I also noted in debugging that the test has to also be run when we are outputting the results.

Comment: Many thanks. 95% of the blanks will be in column B, but I'll see if I can cut my VBA teeth and figure out how to adjust the code for it. Like the blanks, I'm at 95% as well... all formula knowledge in excel.

Comment: @sociologix Take a look at Chip Pearsons page on [Arrays and Ranges in VBA](http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/ArraysAndRanges.aspx) for useful information about this part of the code.

Comment: Thanks Ron. I seem to have successfully modified the VBA so it excludes blank cells from the count:   [If Not vData(I, 1) = "" Then] changed to [  If Not vData(I, 2) = "" Then] in both instances in the regular module.

Comment: @sociologix Yes, that is how I would do it also.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, I solved your problem using this array formula:

```
=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(IF($A$2:$A$21=A2,MATCH($B$2:$B$21,$B$2:$B$21,0),""),MATCH($B$2:$B$21,$B$2:$B$21,0))>0,1))
```

Put this formula into cell `C2` and press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>, then pull formula down. If any questions, comment below

Comment: This works great, thank you! I had forgotten that there are the occasional blank cells in the large list. Is there a way to adjust the formula to continue to count the unique values but ignore the blanks? Currently it throws a #N/A.

Comment: Edit: This works really fast on 1,000 rows test but hits some trouble at 70,000 rows running on (i7-2600K CPU @ 3.40GHz; 16GB RAM; 64 bit WIN 10; Excel 2016). I'll report on exact time once it completes.

Comment: Time update: it took 10 minutes for 1% on 70,000 rows. Might be an overnighter.